# Un-sunken or equivalent

Tags: origin-unknown

What is the word for something that didn't sink.
Example: Can we say "the un-sunken boat" for the boat didn't sink?

Couldn't find anything in internet by search engines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the desired, normal state of a boat is for it not to be sunk, you could just call it a boat.

However, if you want to be more explicit, you could call it

[floating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floating) - buoyed on or in a fluid
or
[afloat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afloat) - borne on or as if on the water

e.g. "the boat was floating in the harbor" or "she's the fastest ship afloat"

Answer (score 1):

The word ***unsunk*** is in the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unsunk).

> adjective *literary*
>
> 1. not sunken; not made to sink
> 2. not lowered or depressed; not brought low either in value, quality, or mood
>
> <sub>*Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers*</sub>

But it says "Used rarely", and the word is not in many other dictionaries, so use with care!

Comment: I can imagine "unsung" making perfect sense in a sentence comparing the boats that did and didn't sink. But "unsunken" would just sound awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to be less literal about the opposite of *sunk*, and use the word [**seaworthy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seaworthy):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : fit or safe for a sea voyage
>   // a *seaworthy* ship

So:

> Those boats that sank and those that remained *seaworthy*.

Comment: Hm, it could be argued that the cause of a ship sinking was not necessarily its unseaworthiness.

Comment: @MrLister But I can't imagine any condition under which a ship could sink and *still* be seaworthy . . . (And I'm not talking about submarines, which I don't believe is the context of the question.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
I wanted to caption the boat in which Jesus traveled and calmed the storm, and then I captioned something like this: "The unsunk boat in the Galilee sea storm"

Comment: @JustinD That context makes a big difference to the answers you'll get. I would definitely add that information to your question. (Had I known that context, I wouldn't have answered in the exact way I did . . .)  I do note that *the* ***unsunk*** *boat* in your comment conveys something different to me than *the* ***unsunken*** *boat* in your question.